# Weather Temperature Expectation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, means

In the below question, I found the answers of the sub-questions as follows,

```
a) (-3*(1/8))+(6*(1/2))+(9*(3/8)) = 6

b) 6^2 = 36

c) (3*6+1)^2 = 19^2 = 361
```

But they turned out to be wrong, I appreciate the help in advance!

```
Tomorrow's weather temperature is modelled as a discrete random variable X and the forecasts reflect
that three values can be considered with certain​ probabilties, as given in the PMF table below. Let 
be a random variable with the probability distribution below.
```

```
m      -3    6     9
Px(m) 1/8   1/2   3/8
```

```
a) The expected temperature for tomorrow will be E(X)?

b) You want to model another random event as a function of X such that Y = X^2. ​Then, E(Y)? 

c) You through that your approach in part b was​ wrong, and Y should be (3X+1)^2 instead of just X^2. 
Then, E(Y)?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b)

$$E(X^2)=(-3)^2\times\frac{1}{8}+6^2\times\frac{1}{2}+9^2\times\frac{3}{8}$$

You calculated $E^2(X)$ instead

c) similarly

Comment: So you say E(X) = (-3*(1/8))+(6*(1/2))+(9*(3/8)) = 6 is true then? @tommik

Comment: @smith.john1919 yes, it is the only one correct

Comment: So c) should be like this am I right? E((3X+1)^2) = (((3*-3+1)^2)*(1/8))+(((3*6+1)^2)*(1/2))+(((3*9+1)^2)*(3/8)) @tommik

Comment: @smith.john1919 yes. If my answer has been useful you can accept it

Comment: Even if your solution seems true, the software I use to do my questions said that this is not correct. What could be the reason? @tommik

Comment: @smith.john1919 pehaps is it broken?

Comment: Don't think so, here is the error it gives to me, https://ibb.co/T8VBDBm @tommik

Comment: @smith.john1919 Exactly what you did... $\Sigma_x xp(x)$

Comment: You can find my calculations in the respective links, a) https://ibb.co/X7DK16p b) https://ibb.co/M2qjtYd c) https://ibb.co/89V2Vmq @tommik

Comment: @smith.john1919 they are correct now. Sure there is an error in the software

Comment: I will try to understand what the problem is, will let you know about the updates @tommik

Comment: It turned out that it was just a software bug. Your answer is totally correct. @tommik